# Quadratic approximation of a multivariables function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion, approximation

Given function $f: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ is second-order differentiable and a constant $L>0$. Prove that the following formula is quadratic approximation of $f$ at point $y$
$$f(y) + \langle \nabla f(y), x-y\rangle + \frac{L}{2}\Vert x-y \Vert^2.$$

My attempt: Let $g(t) = f(tx + (1-t)y),\ t \in [0,1]$. Using Taylor approximation with Langrange residuals for $g$ at $t=0$ we have
$$g(1) = g(0) + g'(0) + \frac{1}{2}g''(\theta),$$
where $\theta \in (0,1)$. Applying the chain rule we have
$$f(x) = f(y) + \langle\nabla f(y),x-y \rangle + $$

I'm stuck here since I don't know how to calculate $g''(\theta)$. May anyone can help me?

Comment: There is some understatement in the question regarding the constant $L$. What if, say, $f(x)=-\|x\|^2$, $y=0$? How in this case the constant can be positive?